# Element undefined error when looping an Array with an empty value

Tags: coldfusion

Hoping someone can give me an idea of what I'm doing wrong.

I'm looping over an array and outputting the values....simply enough.  However if a field is empty I get an `Element <VARIABLE> is undefined in <INDEX>`.

E.g.

```
<cfloop array="#allocationDetails.offerings#" index="myIndex">
#myIndex.name#
#myIndex.number#
#myIndex.somefield#
</cfloop>
```

This works fine until a field has no value.  E.g myIndex.somefield is empty then I get the error:

> "Element somefield is undefined in myIndex"

If I wrap the field output in checks like isDefined("myIndex.somefield") or structKeyExists(myIndex,"somefield") etc, they return true but then I get the error "Element somefield is undefined in myIndex" when I try to output the field value.

I also tried cfdump on the myIndex.somefield and get the same error.

I would have thought this was a pretty basic thing to do but I can't see why this is getting an error. Am I missing something really obvious?

Thanks for your help.

Cheers
Mark

Comment: Can you post the code that creates your array #allocationDetails.offerings#?

Comment: Hi Leigh, sorry but no.  It's just a result set from a webservice call.

Comment: Then perhaps the returned objects are different than what you are thinking. Hard to say without seeing the wsdl. Dump `#myIndex#` (not `myIndex.somefield`). Is it a structure and what keys does it contain?

Comment: are you using CF9? there's isNull()

Comment: Sorry but I would give you access to the WSDL if I was allowed but not only is it protected but is also behind our corporate firewall. Whenever I dump these webservice results I always see a list of methods and return types (methods match the fieldname but have 'get' at the start).  I've used any application to look at the returned data (and types) and these fields are mostly string or Calendar types.  If the field isn't empty the result does appear to be just a string.

Comment: @Henry, I'm trying this on CF8 (Standard) at the moment but I might get my CF9 machine going and see if I have the same issue (and try isNull()).

@Everyone.  I'm also trying to build something to replicate this issue but just having trouble with interruptions and a meeting that is starting soon.

Comment: @tHeSmUrF - Just for grins, what happens if you call the getX method explicitly? ie `<cfset result = myIndex.getSomefield()>
<cfif structKeyExists(variables, "result")>
   #result#
<cfelse>
   it is null
</cfif>`

Comment: @Leigh - That works! However I don't understand why this is required? My original code only generates an error when the value is empty, if it contains anything I can get the value with myIndex.somefield...

Comment: Damn it! :)  I just tried the code (original plus the isNull suggestion from Henry) on CF9 and it works as expected.  Looks like some bug in CF8.  My problem is that we won't be moving our sites to CF9 for another couple of months so I will have to research this a bit further (the app I'm working on needs to be live in a few weeks).  I will still try and come up with some example code that I can post here that show the problem.  Thank you everyone for your help with this.

Comment: @tHeSmUrF - This issue is starting to ring a bell.. But I cannot recall if there was a workaround for CF8.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe there is no array element for that index? For example:

```
<cfscript>
    myArr = ArrayNew(1);
    myArr[1] = 'xx';
    myArr[2] = 'yy';
    myArr[4] = 'zz';
</cfscript>
```

If you try looping through it you could add a ArrayIsDefined check:

```
<cfloop array="#myArr#" index="myIndex">
    <cfif ArrayIsDefined(myArr, myIndex)>
        #myIndex#
    </cfif> 
</cfloop>
```

If not, then there's always try catch:

```
<cfloop array="#myArr#" index="myIndex">
    <cftry>
        #myIndex#
        <cfcatch type="any">
            Error or default variable setting here
        </cfcatch>
    </cftry>
</cfloop>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is totally untested, but have you tried something like this?

```
<cfloop array="#allocationDetails.offerings#" index="myIndex">
    <cfparam name="myIndex.name" default="" />
    <cfparam name="myIndex.number" default="" />
    <cfparam name="myIndex.somefield" default="" />
    #myIndex.name#
    #myIndex.number#
    #myIndex.somefield#
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Sorry Steve, tried cfparam a little while ago and got the same error.

Comment: cfloop array was introduced in CF9.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ColdFusion 9, the error you're getting is due to undefined, or NULL values being returned from the webservice call. Try this instead:

```
<cfif StructKeyExists(myIndex, "somefield") AND NOT IsNull(myIndex.somefield)>
    #myIndex.somefield#
</cfif>
```

Comment: Hi Dan, I'm during this on CF8 but have discovered that I don't have the problem on CF9 machines. Both isDefined and isNull work as expected on CF9. However I have to get this working on CF8 due to the project time constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Dump the #allocationDetails.offerings# and see the output.

You are basically looping over the array. So you will be able to see the outcome of each index value.

Also, May be idiotic but sometimes it works.
Assign the allocationDetails.offerings to a variable and then loop that variable.

```
<cfset some_var = allocationDetails.offerings />
<cfloop array="#some_var#" index="indexNow">
.
.
</cfloop>
```

Finally, 
Also change the variable of index from myIndex to some other name.

Comment: Hi,

Just gave this a go and no different to other code above (i.e. same error).

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfscript>
    allocationDetails.offerings = ArrayNew(1);
    allocationDetails.offerings[1] = {name = 'a', number = 1 , somefield = "somevalue"};
    allocationDetails.offerings[2] = {name = 'a', number = 2 , somefield = "somevalue"};
    allocationDetails.offerings[4] = {name = 'c', number = 3 , somefield = "somevalue"};
</cfscript>
<cfoutput>
<cfloop array="#allocationDetails.offerings#" index="myIndex">
    <cfparam name="myIndex.name" default="" />
    <cfparam name="myIndex.number" default="" />
    <cfparam name="myIndex.somefield" default="" />
    #myIndex.name# : #myIndex.number# :  #myIndex.somefield#<br>
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Steve solution will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Wow this really has me confused.

In the loop (of my real code looping the web service arrays) if I use something like:

```
#StructKeyList(myIndex)#
```

It spits out a list of available keys in myIndex, which includes ALL the field names as expected, including the fields that exist but are empty.

So doing checks like StructKeyExists(myIndex, “somefield”) or isDefined(“myIndex.somefield”) are returning true because the key does exist.  But if I then try to output the field myIndex.somefield I get the Element somefield is undefined in myIndex error.   I don’t understand why this is a problem.  I’ve also tried using  but that doesn’t seem to be doing anything (to my arrays).

If I try all the previous steps on the example array and loops it works as expected. It’s just when I try the above to the results of the web service that I’m having problems.

Has anyone seen this issue when dealing with web service recordsets (on CF8)?

Now onto work arounds….one suggestion that works (thanks Leigh) is rather than using myIndex.somefield is to call the getSomeField method in the web service and use its result instead (which works even if the value is empty).

The other thing that I just tried that is also (for whatever reason) working is dropping the index name from isDefined, so instead of:

```
isDefined(“myIndex.somefield”)
```

I use:

```
isDefined(“somefield”)
```

Again this does appear to be a CF8 related problem because if I run the code on CF9 using StructKeyExists, IsDefined, or IsNull they all work as expected.

Comment: Any difference if you use associative array notation ie `myIndex['someField']`? I would be leery of dropping the index ..  When you do that, what variable is CF referencing? Does `someField` reside in the #variables# scope and does it contain the correct value each time you loop?

Comment: @Leigh - I tried the above but now get: Element UnitName is undefined in a Java object of type class au.edu.nsw.det.tipa.beans.webService.xsd.Offering (relating to the examples, UnitName is someField and Offering is myIndex). I've decided all this is revolving around the values being Null and not empty which is why the isDefined and cfparam etc. tags aren't working as expected. I've decided this morning that we will have to develop for CF9 as I'm writing to much extra code to handle work arounds (I have a few other issues besides this one).  Thank you for all your help with this.

Comment: Yes, that error is essentially the same as the original one. I did not think it would work .. but it was worth a shot. Sounds like CF9 is the way to go on this one.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing something similar. I wanted the average value from an array that could have undefined values. I finally came up with two different ways to do this.

```
<cffunction name="ArrayAvg2">
  <cfargument name="theArray" required="true">
  <cfset sum=0>
  <blockquote>
  <cfloop from=1 to="#ArrayLen(theArray)#" index="i">
    <cfif ArrayIsDefined(theArray, i)>
      <cfoutput>theArray[#i#] = #theArray[i]#</cfoutput>
      <cfset sum += theArray[i]>
    <cfelse>
      Undefined
    </cfif>
    <br/>
  </cfloop>
  </blockquote>

  <cfreturn sum>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="ArrayAvg3">
  <cfargument name="theArray" required="true">
  <cfset sum=0>
  <blockquote>
  <cfloop from=1 to="#ArrayLen(theArray)#" index="arrayElement">
    <cfif ArrayIsDefined(theArray, arrayElement)>
      <cfoutput>theArray[#arrayElement#] = #theArray[arrayElement]#</cfoutput>
      <cfset sum += theArray[arrayElement]>
    <cfelse>
      Undefined
    </cfif>
    <br/>
  </cfloop>
  </blockquote>

  <cfreturn sum>
</cffunction>

<cfset testArray=ArrayNew(1)>
<!--- no testArray[2] --->
<cfset testArray[1]=10>
<cfset testArray[3]=30>

testArray = <cfdump var="#testArray#">
<br/>
ArrayAvg2 = <cfdump var="#ArrayAvg2(testArray)#">
<br/>
ArrayAvg3 = <cfdump var="#ArrayAvg3(testArray)#">
```

I hope this helps.

(BTW, I'm a noobie with ColdFusion, so if you see anything I'm doing wrong let me know!)